# package installation

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I am using ROS noetic on a ubuntu 20.04.1.

I am new to ROS and I am so confused about the package installation.
For example, if I want to install the
[robot localization package](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization),
Do I just git clone it using the following command into my workspace?

```
$git clone -b noetic-devel https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization.git
```

I notice that package can be install through apt, but how can I know that apt command for the package I want?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/365829/package-installation/) by [hank880907](https://answers.ros.org/users/63550/hank880907/) on ROS Answers with karma: 50 on 2020-11-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [praskot](https://answers.ros.org/users/29965/praskot/) on 2020-11-17**:
`sudo apt-get install ros-neotic-robot-localization`

Usually, I do `sudo apt-get install ros-neotic-robot` and then search the available packages using `tab`.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-11-18**:
See #q320046 for a related Q&A.

Summarising: *do not build from source*, unless there is an absolute need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can check if a specific package is released for a specific distro using the [repositories.ros.org Status Pages](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/). Choose the appropriate distro and architecture. I.e. for Noetic, go for [ros_noetic_default](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_noetic_default.html). Then you can search if a package is released and which version has been synced to which package repository (testing, main).

To install packages, basically what @praskot said, is: `sudo apt install ros-<DISTRO>-<PKG>` with all underscores in the package name converted to dashes `-`.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2020-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hank880907](https://answers.ros.org/users/63550/hank880907/) on 2020-11-18**:
That's very helpful!! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to build a package from source, you need to follow the following steps -

- Clone the package to your catkin workspace
- Install all the requisite dependencies using `rosdep` ([link](https://answers.ros.org/question/252478/how-to-build-a-package-from-source-on-ubuntu-mate-1604-lts-and-ros-kinetic/?answer=252502#post-id-252502))
- Build your package (using `catkin build` or `catkin_make` command)
- Source your catkin workspace (using `source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash`)

---

Originally posted by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) with karma: 310 on 2020-11-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hank880907](https://answers.ros.org/users/63550/hank880907/) on 2020-11-18**:
This is also very helpful as well, thank you!